# Custom dialog having mutiple editText and spinners in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to put custom dialog in buttons on click event, and dialog box having multiple textViews and spinners in Android.

How it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Hi check below sample demo app,

http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/04/create-custom-dialog-with-edittext.html

Create layouts as whatever you required like multiple edit text or spinner ,

1) create activity and set theme of dialog in manifest.

OR

2) Create class and extend with dialog and use.

you are set layouts as per your require controls.